# Rellenar Atributo mapeado si la condición de atributo boolean en Entidad Padre se cumple (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate

Tengo tres entidades

```
@Entity
Class Padre{
    //Este id puede pertenecer a 2 Fuentes
    @Basic
    @Column(name="referencia_id")
    @getter @setter private Integer referenceId;
    //Esta variable controla de que fuente viene el Id
    @Basic
    @Column(name="referencia_a")
    @getter @setter private boolean referenciaA

    @ManyToOne
    //En caso que referenciaA == true, llenar esta variable
    @getter @setter private ReferenciaA fuenteA;

   @ManyToOne
   //En cas que referenciaA == false, llenar esta variable
   @getter @setter private ReferenciaB fuenteB;

}

@Entity
//Aqui no existe referenia al Padre, no la necesito
public class ReferenciaA{
   @getter @setter private Id;
}

@Entity
//Aqui tampoco existe referencia a la entidad Padre
public class ReferenciaB{
   @getter @setter private Id;
}
```

El caso es que necesito obtener el objeto ReferenciaA si en el padre el atributo referenciaA es true, si referenciaA es false entonces tengo que traer llena la referenciaB.

Las soluciones que he probado son `@Where` y el `@Filter`, estas tienen la particularidad que el `@Where` filtra del lado de ReferenciaA o ReferenciaB pero no del lado del Padre.

Answer (score 0):

**Encontré la solución.**

Con la anotación `@JoinFormula` puedo pasarle un SQL que me haga el join y el filtro.

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinFormula(value = "(case when referencia_a= 'true' then (select 
                       a.id from esquema.fuenta_a where a.id = fuente_a_id) end)"
        ,referencedColumnName = "id")
 @getter @setter private ReferenciaA fuenteA;

 @ManyToOne

 @JoinFormula(value = "(case when referencia_a= 'false' then (select 
                       b.id from esquema.fuente_b b where b.id = 
 fuente_b_id) end)" ,referencedColumnName = "id")
 @getter @setter private ReferenciaB fuenteB;
```

De esta manera condicionamos si traer la fuenteA o la fuenteB, hay que tomar en cuenta que `referencia_a`es un valor booleano, el valor debemos ponerlo entre comillas, de esta manera: `referencia_a = 'true'`,de lo contrario genera error.